# Why I use indexPathsForSelectedRows to get all cell selected to delete but crashed my app?

Tags: ios, uitableview

Here is some of my code

```
NSArray *selectedRows = [self.playHistoryTableView indexPathsForSelectedRows];
    if (selectedRows.count) {
        for (NSIndexPath *selectionIndex in selectedRows)
        {
            OneSery *sery = [self.playHistoryDic objectAtIndex:selectionIndex.row];
            [CoreDataManager deleteOneHistoryBySeryId:sery.seryId andVideoId:sery.latestVideo.videoId];
            [self.playHistoryDic removeObjectAtIndex:selectionIndex.row];
        }
        [self.playHistoryTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:selectedRows withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    }
```

When select the cells one at a time, it works well. But when multiselect the cell it gonna to crash like this:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
```

I know what it mean but I have no idea where I am wrong. And I tried, when it had three cells and I select the first and second to delete, it delete the first and third cell. When it had only two cells, I select both of them to delete, it does crash my app.
When I debug it, even the `Onesery *sery` value is wrong. So, how could selectionIndex is wrong while selectedRows is right?

### Great thanks to @Wain it's finally done with those:

```
NSArray *selectedRows = [self.playHistoryTableView indexPathsForSelectedRows];
    NSMutableIndexSet *indicesOfItemsToDelete = [[NSMutableIndexSet alloc] init];
    if (selectedRows.count) {
        for (NSIndexPath *selectionIndex in selectedRows)
        {
            OneSery *sery = [self.playHistoryDic objectAtIndex:selectionIndex.row];
            [CoreDataManager deleteOneHistoryBySeryId:sery.seryId andVideoId:sery.latestVideo.videoId];
            [indicesOfItemsToDelete addIndex:selectionIndex.row];
        }
        [self.playHistoryDic removeObjectsAtIndexes:indicesOfItemsToDelete];
        [self.playHistoryTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:selectedRows withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your loop you're doing

```
[self.playHistoryDic removeObjectAtIndex:selectionIndex.row];
```

so you're changing the list of items. On each iteration you try to access an item, but after the first item the next one has moved, because you removed one. For each subsequent item this is worse.

Eventually you get to a point where you try to access an item but so many have been removed that you go past the end of the list, then you crash.

You should get an array of the items to be removed in your loop and remove them all at once after the loop has completed.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I know here is the problem. But I try to do another loop just like the one it deal with the CoreData. But it still failed...

Comment: not a loop, add the items to delete into a new array in your current loop and delete them after (not using the index list now)